# How can I apply a max-height to an iframe but keep it at 100% width?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a relative (not fixed) video background in which YouTube provides the video source.

The main parent container has a max-height of 600px, but in doing this, the bottom part of the YouTube video gets cut off. Is there any way to apply the max-height of 600px to the iframe as well, but keep it at full width and responsive?

HTML

```
<div id="video-container">
  <div class='embed-container'>
    <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOPnzvSrZd4?mute=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=1&loop=1&playlist=YOPnzvSrZd4&start=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="video-area">
    <div class="video-table">
      <div class="video-cell">{video-area:content}</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
#video-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  max-height: 600px;
}
.video-area {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-cell {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.embed-container { 
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.embed-container iframe,
.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think you are asking how to maintain the proper aspect ratio of the video but don't let it get taller than 600px. When you get to a wide screen, the video would be centered but maintain the aspect ratio and on smaller screens you would get a full width video because the height is less than 600px. Does that seem right? Is the video in the code the actual video you are trying to fit or is it the same aspect ratio as the intended video or do you know for sure that it will be 4:3, 16:9, or something else?

Comment: Exactly! Ideally it would create the same result as background-size:cover and background-position: 50% 50% for images. I'd like to account for all types of aspect ratios if possible, but if not, the video above works.

Comment: Cool. You can do it, I or someone else, will post an answer in a bit, but the style will need to to be adjusted per aspect ratio. Unfortunately it won't work as easily as an img tag or background size contain. The trick involves 0 height and percentage top or bottom padding on the child element.

Comment: You're the man, @JasonB! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this one.

Comment: If you use `max-height: 600px` while also using `height: 100%` in the `iframe` the video will adjust nicely based on the `width` of the screen without cutting the video. Have you tried that @Weebs?

Comment: I did, but in applying the max-height: 600px to the iframe, the video is no longer at 100% width.

Comment: So what you want is the video to be `100%` without the black padding right and left, correct?

Comment: @AngelPolitis Exactly, but of course with the max-height: 600px.

Comment: Can this even be done?! Think about it, if you have a `4:3` video and a `16:9` screen the video's width will be quadrupled to be `100%` of the screen, but so will the height _(will reach `12`)_ in order to preserve aspect ratio. If you limit the height, let's say to `10`, either the part of the video exceeding the max-height will be cut or you'll lose aspect ratio.

Comment: Even if the video has the same aspect ratio as the screen, let's say `16:9`, if you limit the maximum height to `600px` the video's width will have to drop  to `~1066px` to preserve ratio. If you force the width to be `100%` and `100% <> 1066px` in the screen either the video is clipped or you lose ratio.

Comment: Okay, there doesn't have to be a max-height:600px, but if the iframe can be vertically aligned to the middle of the #video-container parent <div> - which has the max-height:600px -- that would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the aspect ratio of an element by setting it's height to zero, and adding top or bottom padding as a percentage. It seems odd when you first encounter it, but the percentage padding calculates a percentage of the parent element's width.

The video seems to not be the standard 4:3 or 16:9 but more like 2:3 so I set a `max-height:600px; max-width:900px;` on the parent container. The child container has `width:100%; height:0; padding-top:66.67%;` The 66.67% figure is 2/3 (or 600/900), not some magic number, so you'll need to adjust it for different aspect ratios.

That's it. Now the video will fill the width of the screens that are less than 900px wide and maintain it's aspect ratio of 66.67%. Once the 900px width is exceeded, video is limited so the height won't go over 600px. I put `margin:0 auto` to center it, you'll want to handle the background so it looks good in your design.

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/BYLqod

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a hack, but this works for me when I went across the same case. You can use flex properties to stretch your child div inside parent div.

Made some structure changes to your original one:

```css
#video-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  height:600px;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
 -ms-align-items: stretch;
 -moz-align-items: stretch;
 -o-align-items: stretch;
 align-items: stretch;
}
iframe
{
  width:100%;
}
.video-area {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-cell {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  padding:2em;
  color:white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.embed-container object,
.embed-container embed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
 
    <iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/YOPnzvSrZd4?mute=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0&loop=1&playlist=YOPnzvSrZd4&start=0' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>
 
  <div class="video-area">
    <div class="video-table">
      <div class="video-cell">{video-area:content}</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe
{
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Add this height property to your Iframe